# In Matthew 20:27-28, what is the difference between "being the greatest" and being "the first"?

Tags: matthew

During a recent Bible study, we had a brief discussion about the meaning of Matthew 20:27-28. I read that in biblical times a servant was someone who voluntarily chose to serve another and slaves did not have a choice but were forced to serve their masters one way or another. Servant/Diakonos and slave/bondman/Doulos. Why does one make you "great", and the other "first"? Only one can be "first", so was Jesus speaking of himself?

> Matt 20:26-28 - It shall not be this way among you. Instead, whoever
> wants to become great among you must be your **servant**, and whoever
> wants to be **first** among you must be your **slave**— just as the
> Son of Man did not come to be served, but to serve, and to give His
> life as a ransom for many.”

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While anything Jesus said is significant and rich with potential meaning, most would probably agree that he was using parallelism to reinforce the idea.  Repeating the same thought with nearly the same words serves as a form of emphasis.  Furthermore, it serves to unite the synonymous concepts under one common interest or application.

The Hebrew language, which was commonly used among the Jews even in Jesus' day when the New Testament writers were writing in Greek, often employs poetic parallelism--saying the same thing twice, but in a slightly different wording each time.

In Greek, the word "[πρῶτος/protos](https://www.blbclassic.org/lang/lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G4413&t=KJV)" "first" can mean most important or greatest.  This is also true in English.  Consider the expression "first and foremost" as one example.

The same Greek word translated as "first" or as "chief" (depending on translation) in Matthew 20:27, is used a couple chapters later by Jesus to indicate importance. Notice that here again Jesus parallels the two concepts of "first" and "great."

> This is the **first** and **great** commandment. (Matthew 22:38, KJV; cf. Mark 12:29)

Jesus often used forms of expression in which the same idea was emphasized with parallelism.

Comment: 'First' is primary, foundational, precedent. 'Greatest' is importance, relevance, greatness as such. They are definitely _not_ the same thing or 'parallel', no matter what language is being discussed. They are entirely different conceptual ideas.

Answer (score 2):

In Hebrew/Aramaic the head and first are the same word.  The difference is how the authors translated Jesus' words into Greek.  The idea is the genuine Christian leader is to be a servant.  That's the idea of the Hebrew/Aramaic word for first.

> רִאשׁוֹן S7223 TWOT2097c GK8037182 adj. former, first, chief ... 1. former: a. in time ... 2. first: a. in time ... b. first in degree, chief ... 3. a. fem. c. prep. as adv.; phr.: (1) of time, ...  -
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon* (p. 911). Clarendon Press.

> רֵאשִׁית  ... n.f. beginning, chief  - Ibid., p. 912. Clarendon Press.

In Biblical Aramaic:

> רֵאשׁ S7217 TWOT2983] n.m. Dn 7:6 head (Egyptian Aramaic, S-C; Palm. רש;  רֵישׁ, Syriac ܪܺܝܫ (riš); BH רֹאשׁ);—cstr. ר׳ Dn 7:1; emph. ה—ָ 2:38; sf. רֵאשִׁי 4:2 +, ךְ—ָ 2:28, הּ—ֵ v 32 +, הּ—ַ 7:20, הוֹן—ֵ 3:27; pl. abs. רֵאשִׁין 7:6, sf. רָאשֵׁיהֹם (K§ 53, Anm. b); 63 Gu  ad loc.) Ezr 5:10;— 1. head of man Dn 3:27, cf. 7:9; in vision: of image 2:32, 38, beast 7:6, 20. 2. head as seat of visions, הֶזְוֵי רֵאשָׁךְ, etc., 2:28; 4:2, 7, 10; 7:1, 15. 3. = chief, בְּר׳ Ezr 5:10 in the capacity of their chiefs. 4. sum, essential content, of matters Dn 7:1 (Nes 40 beginning).

- Ibid., p. 1112

Hebrew translations:

וְהֶחָפֵץ לִהְיוֹת בָּכֶם לְרֹאשׁ יְהִי לָכֶם עָבֶד׃
(Matt 20:27, Delitzsch)

וְהֶחָפֵץ לִהְיוֹת רִאשׁוֹן בֵּינֵיכֶם יְהֵא עֶבֶד לָכֶם,
(Matt 20:27, Bible Society in Israel, 2000)